# IIS Transform Manager - Live Stream

Tags: iis, encoding, video-streaming, transform

I've been doing some research and am trying to create a live stream utilizing IIS Smooth Streaming.

What I'm trying to accomplish specifically is this:

1. Upload a video file.
2. Use IIS Transform Manager to encode to Smooth Streaming format.
3. Access the smooth stream as a "live" feed.
4. If additional video files are placed in working folder, encode them and append them to the live stream.

Is something like this possible?